# Can antisymmetry $x\rho y\;\land\;y\rho x\;\implies x=y$ be rewritten

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Can antisymmetry $x\rho y\;\land\;y\rho x\implies x=y$ be rewritten as $(x\rho y\;\land x\ne y)\implies\neg(y\rho x)$ and hold when $x\ne y$ and we have $x\rho y\veebar x\rho y$ May I ask anybody for explanation?

Comment: Yes, it can. Use [Exportation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)).

Comment: Please explain this further. Is that one rule enough or does it need more lines of rewriting? And if so, which rule is used at each line?

Comment: Use Exportation to rewrite it as: $xRy \to (yRx \to x=y)$. Using Contraposition we have : $xRy \to (x \ne y \to \lnot (yRx))$ and using Exportation again: $(xRy \land x \ne y) \to \lnot (yRx)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would approach such a problem.
$$\begin{array}{ccr}
&xRy \,\land\, yRx \Rightarrow x=y &\\
\Leftrightarrow & \neg (xRy \,\land\, yRx) \lor x=y & (A\Rightarrow B\equiv \neg A \lor B) \\
\Leftrightarrow &\neg (xRy) \lor \neg (yRx) \lor x=y & (\text{Duality})\\
\Leftrightarrow & \neg (xRy) \lor x=y \lor \neg(yRx) & (\text{Commutativity of } \lor) \\
\Leftrightarrow & \neg (xRy \land x\neq y) \lor \neg(yRx) & (\text{Duality}) \\
\Leftrightarrow & xRy \,\land\,x\neq y \Rightarrow \neg(yRx) & ( A\Rightarrow B\equiv \neg A \lor B)
\end{array}$$
By duality I mean [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), more precisely, here we're using $\neg (A\land B) \equiv \neg A\lor \neg B$. If one is pedantic enough, they should also note that we're using associativity of $\lor$.

Comment: Thank you, helped alot. Are you using any laws, like maybe idempotens on any of the lines? If so I'd really like to know it.

Comment: Really need to know which rules you used at each line, thank you

Comment: @JeanDoe revised a bit

Comment: What is the rule (A⇒B≡¬A∨B) called?

Comment: Where do you use the associative laws?

Comment: @JeanDoe That's how implication is defined: true if and only if $A$ is false or $B$ is true. Associativity is used just to group certain parts of the formula (as required for the uses of the rules).

Comment: Ok, but are you 100% sure ¬(xRy)∨¬(yRx)∨x=y can be rewritten as  ¬(xRy)∨x=y∨¬(yRx)? Where you refer to the commutative law.

Comment: If there is anything wrong in the rewriting of the laws, im gonna get an F tomorrow

Comment: Well, if you don't get an F, then my take should be correct by your own statement. I can hardly wait :)